# Non-degenerate bilinear forms of Lie algebra with a degenerate Killing form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

**Definition**: A Lie algebra is defined by:
$$
[e_a,e_b]={f_{ab}}^ce_c
$$
The Killing form is
$$
g_{ab}=-{f_{ac}}^d {f_{bd}}^c
$$

---

**Set-Up**:
The type of Lie algebra of our interests (found out during a physics research) have $e_a$ with $a=1,2,3,4$, four generators.
The form of structure constant is given by
$$
[e_3,e_i]=\epsilon_{ij} e_j,\;\;\; [e_i,e_j]=\epsilon_{ij} e_4,\;\;\;\;\;
$$
(with generators $e_j$ of Lie group) and others Lie brackets (commutators) are zeros. Here $i, j$ are only $1,2$.

The Killing form of this algebra can be explicitly computed as a degenerate Killing form:
$$
g_{ab}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0& 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 2& 0\\
0 & 0& 0& 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Question**: **How to determine/construct non-degenerate invariant bilinear form $\Omega_{ab}$ for this Lie algebra?**

Please be **specific to focus** on this special case (instead of being **vague** on outlining the general procedure). Many thanks!

Comment: The space of invariant symmetric (resp. alternate) bilinear forms has dimension 10 (resp 6), you should compute (as a linear algebra problem, which can take a little time) the space of invariant ones. Maybe you'll have to discuss on the scalars $\epsilon_{ij}$ at some point (your definition of the Lie algebra law is somewhat unclear at this point, since you don't say what are $i,j$). Also mentioning the Killing form is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks Yves, let me see. Thank you for the comment really.

Comment: Here $i,j$ are in {1,2}. This Lie algebra is $E^c_2$ algebra type, which also has a $2n+2$ dimensional generalization. Here it is $2+2=4$ dimensional. There are just 4 generators.

Comment: Is this the ONLY requirement to find bilinear invariant $\Omega_{ab}$, by $$ {f_{IJ}}^a\Omega_{ab}={f_{Ib}}^a\Omega_{aJ}$$?

Comment: If I understand correctly your notation, the equations should have the form $f_{cd}^a\Omega_{ab}=f^a_{db}\Omega_{ca}$ ($\forall b,c,d$). You can suppose $\Omega$ symmetric or antisymmetric to have 10 or 6 unknown instead of 16.

Comment: @ Yves: Can $\Omega$ uniquely define? If not, what does that mean mathematically?

Comment: I can't guess what you mean by "Can Omega uniquely define?".